# How to pass array list using intent in android

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent

> How can i pass array list from one activity to another activity using intent.

**From activity**

```
 ArrayList<ServicesInfo> bookedService = new ArrayList<ServicesInfo>();`
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , Proceedtocart.class);
                intent.putExtra("Listview",bookedService);
                startActivity(intent);
```

**To activity**

```
 bookedService = (ArrayList<BookedInfo>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Listview");
```

> while running am getting error as "java.lang.runtimeexception parcel unable to marshal value android"
>
> Help to to fix this issue

Comment: I implemented parcelable in my ServiceInfo array but still same error occuring

Comment: Show us your `ServiceInfo`

Comment: Try intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", my_list);. It will solve your problem. For this, you need to make your ServiceInfo parceable.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Listview", bookedService);
startActivity(intent);
```

and on NextActivity :

```
yourArrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Listview");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public class ContactInfo {

  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private int idx;

// get and set methods
}



 public class ContactInfo implements Parcelable {

      private String name;
      private String surname;
      private int idx;

    // get and set method

    @Override
        public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(surname);
        dest.writeInt(idx);
    }

    // Creator
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public ContactInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ContactInfo(in);
    }

    public ContactInfo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ContactInfo[size];
        }
    };

    // "De-parcel object
    public ContactInfo(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        surname = in.readString();
        idx = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

Put

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
// Contact Info
ContactInfo ci = createContact("Francesco", "Surviving with android", 1);
i.putExtra("contact", ci);
```

Get

```
Intent i = getIntent();

ContactInfo ci = i.getExtras().getParcelable("contact");

tv.setText(ci.toString()); // tv is a TextView instance
```